# React Test Renderer, useEffect async useState update does not seem to update state

Tags: react-hooks, jestjs, react-functional-component, react-test-renderer

I am using react-test-renderer to test a function component and can't seem to mock an update to the state via the useEffect hook.

Here is my component:

```
const BarCodeScanScreen = ({ language = "" }: LocalizationContextProps) => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
  }, []);
  ...
})
```

and the corresponding test:

```
import { BarCodeScanner, PermissionResponse, PermissionStatus } from "expo-barcode-scanner";
import React from "react";
import { create, act } from "react-test-renderer";
import BarCodeScanScreen from "../BarCodeScanScreen";

describe("BarCodeScanScreen", () => {

  it("renders correctly if permission is granted", async () => {
    const mockPermissionPromise:Promise<PermissionResponse> = new Promise((resolve) => ({
      status: PermissionStatus.GRANTED, 
      expires: "never", 
      granted: true, 
      canAskAgain: true,
    }));

    const permissionRequestSpy = jest.spyOn(BarCodeScanner, 'requestPermissionsAsync').mockReturnValue(mockPermissionPromise);
    let tree;
    await act( async () => {
      tree = create(<BarCodeScanScreen />);
    });
    expect(permissionRequestSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
    permissionRequestSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

The permissionRequestSpy attempts to mock the return value of the `BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync()` and `expect(permissionRequestSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()` passes but the expected component state update based on `hasPermission` does not seem to take place in the snapshot.

Does it look like this test is being set up correctly to mock a response to the permission request in the useEffect hook, rendering an update to the BarCodeScanScreen component?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: were you able to solve this? @Ian Dershem